# How to fix layering issue with React, CSS and Flexbox

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I am trying to layer two containers on top of one another, but instead it is being placed in a column

I have looked into z-index and layering, but it does not seem to be working.

My code:
class App extends Component {

render() {

```
let bigContainer = {
  height: '30vh',
}

let containerOne = {
  height:'100%',
  zIndex:1,
  position: 'relative'
}

let containerTwo = {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    zIndex: 100,
    height: '100%',
    position: 'relative'
}

let innerStyleOne = {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    height: '15vh',
    position: 'relative',
    order: '2',
    width: '100%'
}

let innerStyleTwo = {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    height: '15vh',
    position: 'relative',
    order: '2',
    width: '100%'
}

let innerStyleLayer = {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    position: 'relative',
    height: '25px',
    width: '25px'
}

return (
  <div className="App" style={bigContainer}>
    <div style = {containerOne}>
      <div style={innerStyleOne}> </div>
      <div style={innerStyleTwo}> </div>
    </div>
    <div style = {containerTwo}>
      <div style={innerStyleLayer}></div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

}
}

This is the result I'm getting
[image]

but i am trying to get the green square in the middle of the blue and black bars

Edit: after changing container2 to position:absolute
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using 
position: relative for bigContainer and
position: absolute for containerTwo.

Comment: I changed position to absolute but it just moves to the side, I added an edit that shows what happens

Comment: class containerTwo
using: top: 50%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%,-50%)

Comment: that works, but why do we have to add the top, left, and transform?

Comment: Sorry. I do not speak English very well.
u can see more here https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/pr_class_position.asp